# Bulk inserting data gives error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert, sqldatatypes

Attempting to bulk insert into a table and I am getting the error:

```
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 31, column 4 (Birthday).
```

Below is the code I am trying to use to insert the data:

```
Bulk Insert Dzt.dbo.Player
    From 'A:\New Folder\Seed_Files\Player.csv'
    With
    (
        FieldTerminator=',',
        RowTerminator='\n',
        FirstRow=2
    )
```

Here is the code I used when making the table:

```
Use Dzt

Create Table Player
(
Player_ID int,
FirstName varchar(255),
LastName varchar(255),
Birthday date,
Email varchar(255),
L_Flag varchar(255)
);
```

This is my first attempt at making a table and inserting data so I am thinking it is likely a datatype error for the Birthday field but I have been unable to find anything online that I am able to grasp my head on at this time. I have also tried use the datatype datetime instead of date but I received the same error.

I am using SSMS 2012 to create and insert the data onto a 2012 SQL Server.

Let me know if there is anything else I can provide that might help.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspect it could be a date format error, I would suggest importing the csv into a table with Birthday column set to varchar type. Then use this query to filter the erroneous records.

```
select birthday from temptable where isdate(birthday) = 0
```

You could then correct those records and then insert them into your old table.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However I was able to find my issue. As it turns out on the rows with the errors the last name field had something like " Jones, Jr." and since my Fieldterminator was "," it was throwing errors. I edited the source file to remove these "," and everything inserted properly.